# Extracting audio and video at twice the playing speed

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to output the audio from an `mp4` file as an `ogg` file.  And have a `webm` video at twice the playing speed without audio.

Would be using the following commands for the task

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
       -vn \
       -acodec libvorbis \
       -aq 5\
       output.ogg

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
       -an \
       -filter:v "setpts=2.0*PTS" \
       -c:v libvpx-vp9\
       0 \
       output.webm
```

What would be a good strategy so as to run the two commands for all files in my current directory?

A few years ago, I was converting videos to `ogv` but have seen that `webm` is today more popular.  Is `webm` the way to go these days?

Having started with options such as `-aq 5`, I wonder whether this would really be necessary.  Ideally I would keep everything the same rather than messing with too many details for my conversion.

Comment: Part of the question seems to be fairly easy to test - you run the commands against one of your files and inspect the result. The second part would then to run these commands against every file in your current directory, which can be done straightforwardly with a loop command (`for mp4 in *.mp4; do ...commands...; done`)

Comment: Is there any way to test the video parameters of the output?

Comment: You could look at the resulting video

Comment: Have looked at the properties for the audio, but found no information.

Comment: An audio file won't contain video information

Comment: I have doubts upon whether to use `-aq 5` or not use it at all.

Comment: Fair point. Put in your question so that it's clear this is want you need advice for

Comment: I could look at the resulting video but it is taking too long.  The description seems counter intuitive.  I have a video running for `90 minutes`, but want output to take `45 minutes`.  What would be the appropriate `pts`?  Is it `0.5*PTS` or `2.0*PTS`,